# Custom Deserializer in Json

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to implement a custom Json mapping to the POJO below at class level.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DeviceDeserializer.class)
 public class Pojo {
   private String device;
   private String port;
   private String reservbleBw;
   *default constructor, getter and setters*
 }
```

Below is my Json File

```
[
  {
   "Device":"ABCD",
   "ifces":[
     {
      "port":"ABCD:1/2/0",
      "reservableBW":"1000",
      "capabilites":[ "MPLS" ]
    },
    {
      "port":"ABCD:1/2/1",
      "reservableBW":"100",
      "capabilites":[ "ETHERNET" ]
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

Now i only need to map the ports and reservableBw when 'capabilities' is 'ETHERNET'. I looked at few examples of custom deserializer but i do not know how to pass the value for JsonParser and DeserializationContext. I have problem understanding the below line.

```
  public Pojo deserialize(JsonParser jParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
 // custom deserializer implementation
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "I do not know how to pass the value for JsonParser and DeserializationContext". You registered custom deserializer, and Jackson will use that deserializer, you don't need to pass anything, you will be passed these values by Jackson.

Comment: You will be passed these values by Jackson?  I'm reading Json objects from a file. Now how can I use json parser to parse?

Comment: Can you elaborate? because I never used this

Comment: If you gone so far as to use custom deserializers, how come you don't know how the basic case works? It's in every Jackson tutorial ever pretty much.

Comment: JsonParser being passed json properties so that I could use to return a custom object. But I have no idea as so how they got those values? Who n where it's passed in? It's sort of confusing because those two parameters came from no where.

Comment: I would appreciate if you send me links that talks about how jsonparser gets its values? Or clear my doubt I may have got something totally wrong here.

Comment: They don't come from "nowhere" they are instantiated and used by Jackson library, these are classes that have knowledge of JSON parse rules. You should not be concerned by where they came from (way's a plenty), you should be concerned be how to fulfill your contract - in this case, parsing values so that a `Pojo` instance is produced in the end. But if you really must, [Jackson is open source](https://github.com/codehaus/jackson).

Comment: My target is json file. Previously I was using objectmapper and gave  the path in the constructor. But in this case how json parser or whatever would know the target file to parse?

Comment: Because you gave it to the parser?

Comment: I really have not provided path of file anywhere. How could parser know where to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to solve your issue:

Method 1: use a middle object to mapper: I have created a demo for your issue see [this](https://github.com/xmeng1/jackson-examples).

Create a middle object to mapper the original JSON

```
public class SfPojoDto {
    private String device;
    private List<Ifce> ifces;
}

public class Ifce {
    private String port;
    private String reservableBW;
    private String[] capabilites;
}
```

Then use custom deserializer to mapper it firstly and convert to your target object.

```
public class DeviceDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SfPojo> {
    @Override
    public SfPojo deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // while (p.nextToken()!=null) {
        //     if (p.getCurrentToken()==)
        // }
        String temp = p.readValueAsTree().toString();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SfPojoDto sfPojoDto = mapper.readValue(temp, SfPojoDto.class);
        SfPojo sfPojo = new SfPojo();
        sfPojo.setDevice(sfPojoDto.getDevice());
        List<Ifce> ifceList = sfPojoDto.getIfces();
        for (Ifce ifce : ifceList) {
            List<String> capabilities = Arrays.asList(ifce.getCapabilites());
            if (capabilities.contains("ETHERNET")) {
                sfPojo.setPort(ifce.getPort());
                sfPojo.setReservbleBw(ifce.getReservableBW());
                return sfPojo;
            }
        }
        return sfPojo;
    }
}
```

Method 2: you can use the JsonParser to operate the JSON string, but this method is more complicated, you can ref [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/):

Comment: Everything s fine. But I just want to know how jsonparser gets its value. Is that something calling this customdeserializer passing in those parameters?

Comment: You can check the full jsonparser javadoc https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html. Usually, you can get all string by using `p.readValueAsTree().toString()` or get property string by using `p.getText()` or you can iterate all the tokens by `p.nextToken()`

Comment: I do not want to know about parser. I can handle once I get the parser object that contains data. how do you call this to make it work?

Comment: I still cannot understand what you mean. You mean how Jackson invoke custom deserializer?

Comment: Yes and the parameters as well and What is the value of temp?

Comment: I think the Jackson use the annotation to intercept the JSON string data to the  JsonParser, so if you put the @JsonDeserialize(using = DeviceDeserializer.class) before your class, the JsonParser will contain all the JSON string. if put it before the field, the JsonParse will contain the JSON string for the field. You can check the other example in my shared repository.

Comment: The variable of temp is trying to get the JSON string from the JsonParse. If you want to understand how Jackson do this work, I think you need to read the Jackson source code.

Comment: 'The variable of temp is trying to get the JSON string from the JsonParse' Where does JsonParse get its value from? In   https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/  the JsonParser is read from the file. But how does it work in the above scenario?

Comment: Have you git clone my repository? maybe you can set a breakpoint in the custom deserializer and you will understand the process of Jackson custom deserializer.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But the only thing missing is that how the call to Pojo object happens?. Is it just the same way as you do with object mapper? like Mapper.readAsValue(new file(//'));

Comment: Yes check with this Unit test https://github.com/xmeng1/jackson-examples/blob/master/uncategory/src/test/groovy/SfPojoSpec.groovy  `def "Deserialize the SfPojo with custom deserializer"()` I am using the spockframework for unit test which is similar with JUnit

Comment: 1. read the file and get the string of JSON; 2. ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(). 3.  SfPojo input = mapper.readValue(json, SfPojo.class). If the code is helpfull, please accept it, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. But I made few modifications in your code. I do not want to use DTO and traverse because my file is kind of big. So i converted JsonParser to JsonNode and parsed it on the fly.

Comment: Cheer ! JsonNote is a lower level of Jackson, if you want to operate the JSON in depth, you can use JsonNode. The disadvantage is that you need to maintain more code and more unit test to keep your code is always right.

Answer (score 0):

Your model:

```
public class Ifce {

    public String port;
    public String reservableBW;
    public List<String> capabilites = null;

}

public class Device {
    public String device;
    public List<Ifce> ifces = null;

}
```

Then use the objectMapper like this:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
Device device = objectMapper.readValue(yourJsonData, Device.class)
List<Ifce> deviceList  = device.ifces.find { it.capabilites.contains("ETHERNET")}
```

Comment: This will map all the ports but I want only those with capabilities ETHERNET. This is my current implementation.

Comment: I believe its easier just to find the items you are interested in rather than over-engineer the parser.. I have not tested the specific find function but something like that should do what you are looking for

Comment: Does the above code iterate twice the whole file? I do not want to do that if that's the case.

Comment: 1. It does deserialize the JSON to a POJO with all data into an Device object
2. Creates and List with all Ifces objects containing the ETHERNET

Reads Json once..